# Wix: After move files from Component to another one - upgrade incorrect

Tags: file, wix, components, upgrade

I have 2 version of installer created by using wix. Old version differents of new version by files in components: some files from one component was moved to another one:

Was:

```
<!--OLD version-->
<Component Id="Component_1" Guid="{43E78920-7C99-412d-A69C-8017DA608D8D}">
  <File DiskId='1' Name="File_1.dll"/>
  <File DiskId='1' Name="File_2.dll"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="Component_2" Guid="{520261C3-0608-46d1-A284-6BED54DD525A}" KeyPath="yes">
  <File DiskId='1' Name="File_3.dll"/>
</Component>
```

now:

```
<!--NEW version-->
<Component Id="Component_1" Guid="{43E78920-7C99-412d-A69C-8017DA608D8D}">
  <File DiskId='1' Name="File_1.dll"/>
  <File DiskId='1' Name="File_3.dll"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="Component_2" Guid="{520261C3-0608-46d1-A284-6BED54DD525A}" KeyPath="yes">
  <File DiskId='1' Name="File_2.dll"/>
</Component>
```

File_3.dll move from "Component_2" to "Component_1" and File_2.dll move to "Component_2" from "Component_1".

All components included at the same Feature.

Now, after installation new version over old version result is next: File_3.dll is exist but other files has been deleted.

I wish new version only upgrade old version files.

How does resolve this problem?